# TemplateSyntaxError : No module named braintree in paypal template?

Tags: python, django, paypal, django-paypal, braintree

I am making a project that sells product and 
I want to have a payment using paypal in my django. but I got this error :

> 'billing_tags' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading billing.templatetags.billing_tags: No module named braintree

In my `settings.py` i have already put `'paypal.standard.ipn'` in `INSTALLED_APPS` and the `PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL`.

When I check to my python shell..

```
>>> from billing import get_integration
>>> get_integration("pay_pal")
<billing.integrations.pay_pal_integration.PayPalIntegration object at 0x9d41b0c>
```

it means, it is working...

In my `urls.py`, I have this:

```
from billing import get_integration
pay_pal = get_integration("pay_pal")
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^paypal-ipn-handler/', include(pay_pal.urls)),
)
```

In my views.py :

```
from billing import get_integration
from paypal.standard.forms import PayPalPaymentsForm
def booking_save_page(request, id):
.....
form = BookTicketForm(request.GET)
if form.is_valid():
    inst = Ticket.objects.create(
               date_select = form.cleaned_data['date_select'],
               product_name = product.name,
               quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity'],
               totalcost = form.cleaned_data['totalcost'],
               price = form.cleaned_data['price'],
               first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
               last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
               contact = form.cleaned_data['contact'],
               product = product,
               client = client,
               trans_code = code,
               email = form.cleaned_data['email'],
               memo = form.cleaned_data['memo'],
               status = 'Pending',
               created = now,
               )
    pay_pal = get_integration("pay_pal")
    pay_pal.add_fields({
           "business": "ccfiel@gmail.com",
           "item_name": product.name,
           "invoice": inst.id,
           "notify_url": settings.BASE_DNS + "/paypal-ipn-handler/",
           "return_url": settings.BASE_DNS + str(client.id) + '/book/'+str(inst.id) +'/success/?booksaved=1',
           "cancel_return": settings.BASE_DNS + str(client.id) + '/?booksaved=0',
           "amount": inst.totalcost})
    form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=pay_pal)
    context = {"form": form}
    return render_to_response("pay_pay.html", context)
 ......
```

and my template `pay_pay.html` have only this:

```
<h1>Pay Here</h1>
{{ form.render }}
```

I think the problem is in rendering the `pay_pay.html` in my views... why i got this error:

> 'billing_tags' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading billing.templatetags.billing_tags: No module named braintree

Does anyone have an idea about my situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `pip install braintree` in a terminal and reload your server.